# Would any place patch a tire with a nail 1 inch from side

Tags: tires

[image][image]

I recently got a flat due to a nail of some sort.  The place I took it to won't patch because "the patches are round and the hole is too close to the edge".

So now because I drive an awd vehicle (2018 highlander with 19s), I'll need to change all 4 tires (Bridgestone duellers) with 18k miles on them.

Part of me just wonders if they would rather just sell $1k worth of tires than fix one... so,  would any place patch this? Maybe there are better types of patches for something like this? Any alternatives?

Comment: I've no idea about your specific tires, but will they take an inner tube? That would certainly be cheaper than a set of new tires.

Comment: Just an FYI to anyone coming here... my tires are good for another couple years or so... I didn't want to have to buy all 4 new tires because of this one bad one. I searched used tires on ebay for the exact model and size of tire and found several with similar tread depth... bought one of those and had a local shop install it. Everything worked out well and the tire and installation only cost about $75 total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any shop worth going to would give the same answer.

Those constraints are based on previous failures where tires failed in service due to repairs that proved to be the cause.

A cheap repair and then a high-speed blowout entering a bend with some or all your family on board... There is really no sensible choice.

And 18k on them - they did well... I only get two seasons (ie 2 winters or 2 summers) on mine and they get changed anyway.

I read another answer on here that mentioned some tire shops (few apparently now) have "shaving" machines that can reduce the tread depth on a new tire to match the old ones ... Hmm, would I do that..? Think I would go with no...

Comment: Kind of figured that might be the case. 18k isn't much though for tires that give 80k guarantees

Comment: @smerny 80k guarantee - well not seen where I am... but see update...

Comment: Thinking about finding a used one on ebay with similar tread